# Download Excel Package File to Local Computer in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm publishing Web Application on VM Server in domain. I want to let users download the Excel file to his local computer. I want to show Save File Box and ask user about FileName and FilePath? My simple doesn't work, it saves only file on server. I deleted SQL query and connections settings in example below:

```
public ActionResult ZW2(ZW_Query model)
{
        string parametra = model.paremetr1;
        string parametrb = model.paremetr2;
        string parametrc = model.paremetr3;
        string parametrd = model.paremetr4;
        string parametre = model.paremetr5;

        if (parametra == "*")
        {
            parametra = "%";
        }
        else
        {
            parametra = model.paremetr1;
        }

        List<Models.ZWPub> list = new List<Models.ZWPub>();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
            {
                String sql;

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

                da.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string filename = "Zamowienia.xlsx";
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), filename.Replace(".xlsx", DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".xlsx"));
                    FileInfo Files = new FileInfo(filePath);
                    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
                    ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(Files);
                    var sheetscreate = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Zamowienia");

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        sheetscreate.Cells[1, i + 1].Value = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            sheetscreate.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Value = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    excel.Save();

                    FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
                    var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                    result.FileDownloadName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

                    return result;
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ZW2", "GM", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", target = "_blank" }))
{
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Podaj numer ZW.</h4>
                <h5 class="redfont">Numery zamówień podawaj kolejno od góry.</h5>

                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.paremetr1, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.paremetr1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = "*", @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.paremetr1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.paremetr2, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.paremetr2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = "*", @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.paremetr2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.paremetr3, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.paremetr3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = "*", @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.paremetr3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.paremetr4, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.paremetr4, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = "*", @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.paremetr4, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.paremetr5, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.paremetr5, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = "*", @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.paremetr5, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Uruchom" class="btn btn-default" />
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Powrót" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "GM")'" />
                    </div>
                </div>
}
```

Comment: This is happening because you are calling excel.Save() on the server. You need to return something like a FileStreamResult to your browser. Could you show your whole method?

Comment: @PatrickMcvay Sure, I edited the first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are never returning the file to the browser. One way to accomplish this is to use System.IO.FileStream and FileStreamResult.

```
        string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), filename.Replace(".xlsx", DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".xlsx"));

        FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);

        var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        result.FileDownloadName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        return result;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210835/discussion-on-answer-by-patrick-mcvay-download-excel-package-file-to-local-compu).